# Алгоритм сжатия ДНК-последовательностей для хранения геномов на сервере с очень быстрой распаковкой

Tags: php, алгоритм, строки, потоки-данных, биоинформатика

Встала необходимость держать ряд геномов на веб-сервере (различного рода утилиты для биоинформатиков, генетиков и биологов/медиков, в целом). А это, как оказывается, стало недешево :) Объёмы большие, доступ нужен файловый (так проще для скриптов), возникает явное желание как-то запаковать так, чтобы они занимали мало места, но при этом очень быстро и без большой нагрузки на CPU распаковывались. Стандартные варианты, издавна используемые в биоинформатике (потоковые на базе gzip), не очень хороши: жмут в 2.5 - 4 раза (в принципе, неплохо), но большие затраты CPU и памяти.

Геном изначально - это текстовый файл с малым алфавитом. Пока используем придуманную ещё в стародавние времена идею: поскольку алфавит состоит всего лишь из 5 букв определений для нуклеотидов (A, G, T, C, N), то используем полубайтовое кодирование. Конкретно:

```
А 0001
C 0010
G 0100
T 1000
N 1111
```

Преобразуем текст в обычный файл. Размер файла сокращается в два раза (чуть больше, чем в два за счёт удаления символа возврата каретки), операции сравнения можно проводить побитово, что увеличивает производительность скриптов.

Хочется большего. Навскидку, идеи:

1. Четвертьбайтовое кодирование, но тогда пропадает N (это обозначение любого нуклеотида, т.е. A или G или C или T) и поиск подстрок становится дольше
2. Замена последовательности одинаковых нуклеотидов, например, AAAAAAAAA, на что-то вида ЧИСЛО;СИМВОЛ. Минусы: разворачивать в память, дополнительные коды парсинга (хотя 0000 никто не запрещал)

Плюс, эпидемия COVID-19 (РНК-вирус, а не ДНК) однозначно добавила необходимость хранения РНК, т.е. добавляется пятый символ - U вместо Т (понятно, что можно просто помечать, что это РНК, а не ДНК, но тогда теряется универсальность).

Гиганты, вроде Qiagen, используют, судя по всему, полубайтовое кодирование. Но на то они и гиганты, могут себе позволить большие затраты.

Может, мы не видим что-то, лежащее на поверхности, и есть простой способ сэкономить пространство не в 2, а, скажем, в 3 раза?

В качестве примера: подборка вариаций вируса иммунодефицита человека (не содержит N), формат FASTA (смотреть как текстовый файл, 39 МБ)  и 17-я хромосома человека (текст, фактически одна строка, 79 МБ). Доступны на Яндекс-диске: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/4E-_ed6QT6AVug

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137851/discussion-on-question-by-viktor-tomilov----).

Comment: мысль ( может и дурацкая)):
на большом объеме днк выделить эталонную (шаблонную).
И потом сохранять только отличия от нее. Затрат на кодирование смещения+данные будет больше, но зависит от их(diffs) количества.
нужен стат анализ

Comment: @MichaelChechin Проверялось неоднократно. Увы, на реальных ДНК не работает :(   В целом, идея неплоха, но используется для обнаружения повторов. К сожалению, семейств повторов в геномах очень много.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Работает, называется SNP. Но да, применимость зависит от того, что храним.

Answer (score 1):

Если считать что все пять букв встречаются равновероятно, то теоретический предел плотности упаковки равен *log<sub>5</sub>256* (*≅ 3.4454*). Практические комбинации для блоков из различного количества байтов, упорядоченные от самой плотной упаковки к самой неплотной:

> ```
> байты  нуклеотиды  плотность  % от макс. плотности
>   7        24       3.4286     99.5112
>   5        17       3.4000     98.6819
>   8        27       3.3750     97.9563
>   6        20       3.3333     96.7470
>   3        10       3.3333     96.7470
>   4        13       3.2500     94.3283
>   2         6       3.0000     87.0723
>   1         3       3.0000     87.0723
> ```

Верхняя граница - восемь байт, потому что распаковка/запаковка требуют целой арифметики. Современный компьютер обрабатывает за раз 64 бита - восемь байт.

Последние две строки таблицы: в один байт можно запаковать три нуклеотида. Потери - 13% от теоретического максимума.

Первая строка: 24 нуклеотида в семи байтах с плотностью очень близкой к максимальной. Потери около половины процента.

Упаковка/распаковка не сложная и очень быстрая. Произвольный доступ тоже возможен. Даже поиск по упакованному файлу можно сделать, но это сложнее.

**P.S.** Для алфавита из шести символов теоретический максимум плотности упаковки 3.0948. Таблица очень простая - самая плотная упаковка - три символа на байт. Около трёх процентов потерь:

> ```
> байты  нуклеотиды  плотность  % от макс. плотности
>   8        24       3.0000     96.9361
>   7        21       3.0000     96.9361
>   6        18       3.0000     96.9361
>   5        15       3.0000     96.9361
>   4        12       3.0000     96.9361
>   3         9       3.0000     96.9361
>   2         6       3.0000     96.9361
>   1         3       3.0000     96.9361
> ```

Comment: Если задача ещё актуальна, я готов помочь с упаковкой/распаковкой.

Comment: Эта задача до сих пор актуальна, даже в биоинф. облаках. Вопрос именно в соотношении сжатие/нагрузка (скорость тоже важна но это меньший фактор). Ну, и еще - потоковый алгоритм или нет. Если нет, но при этом коэффициент сжатия будет лучше, чем у, к примеру, GZIP, то такой алгоритм тоже найдёт применение, но уже в системах хранения.

Comment: Алгоритм жмёт блоки по 24 нуклеотида. То есть ему не нужна память для сжатия/распаковки. Я попробую сделать прототип и посмотрю как он сжимает на практике. Его можно сочетать с GZIP.